# Dropzone Success function not working

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Dropzone on a website but I am facing a problem getting the success message. Below is my code.

```
var mydropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzonejs-example", {
  url: "/Home/FilesUpload/",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
      formData.append("is_visible", $('#is_visible').is(':checked'));

      this.removeFile(file);
      this.on("success", function(fname) {
        console.log("ok");
      });
    });
  },
});

$("#uploadbtn").click(function() {
  mydropzone.processQueue();
});
```

My controller returns a string so I want to catch the string here. How can it be possible or where am I doing the mistake? Please correct my code.

Comment: Are you having problem receiving the response? the document says "The file has been uploaded successfully. Gets the server response as second argument."  Can you try this? that is try receiving the server response as second argument.

Comment: i think you need to place your on("succes) outside of your function.. see here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html all functions are outside the actual var mydropzone

Comment: Not working , Tried both methods